# ActionBarSherlock tab based app crashes on older Android devices

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

After having read quite a lot about it I decided to use ActionBarSherlock to provide a modern look and at the same time support older Android versions.

I created an Android tab based application using the Eclipse Project wizard and modyfied it to use ActionBarSherlock. The result of the main activity is like this:

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragment;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements ActionBar.TabListener {

    private static final String STATE_SELECTED_NAVIGATION_ITEM = "selected_navigation_item";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Set up the action bar.
        final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(false);

        // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_tab_1).setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_tab_2).setTabListener(this));
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.title_tab_3).setTabListener(this));
    }
    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    }    
}
```

The manifest file looks like this:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.comp.test"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="android.app.TabActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

When I run it on an Android 4.0.4 device it works fine but when running it on an Android 2.3.3 device it crashes in the "setContentView" line. Any ideas why?

Thanks.

Comment: What kind of crash do you see? Can you post the layout XML?

Comment: What's the App Theme? Did you use the sherlock Theme?

Comment: The layout file looks like this:

<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

Comment: And the Theme looks like this on older (pre v. 11)

<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />

</resources>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use ActionBar Sherlock you'll have to use This Theme instead: 
`Theme.Sherlock.Light`